# Back em txt de dados

Tags: php

eu tenho uma tabela do meu blog chamada noticas, nesta tabela noticias eu tenho os campos, id, titulo, texto, autor, data

gostaria de criar um botão aonde ao clicar nele ele cria um arquivo .txt com todas as informações vindas do meu banco de dados ex:

```
id: 1
titulo: titulo da noticia 1
texto: texto da noticia 1
autor: autor do post 1
data: data do post 1

id: 2
titulo: titulo da noticia 2
texto: texto da noticia 2
autor: autor do post 2
data: data do post 2


id: 3
titulo: titulo da noticia 3
texto: texto da noticia 3
autor: autor do post 3
data: data do post 3
```

e por ai vai indo.. pegando todos os dados do DB como posso estar fazendo isso ?

Comment: Abre o arquivo com o `fopen()`, percorre os registros escrevendo no arquivo, com `fwrite()`, e no final fecha-o com `fclose()`. Já tentou alguma coisa?

Answer (score 0):

#### Exemplo

Faça a query no banco, e mande imprimir com essa função:

```
function gravar($texto){
    //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo.
    $arquivo = "nomedoarquivo.txt";
    //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
    //Escreve no arquivo aberto.
    fwrite($fp, $texto . ";");
    //Fecha o arquivo.
    fclose($fp);
}
```

No exemplo, está separando por ";", aí fica a critério usar quebra de linha, etc. Basicamente como imprimir uma tabela/lista.

---

#### Referências

[Escrever e ler arquivo txt](http://satellasoft.com/?materia=escrever-e-ler-em-arquivo-txt-com-php)